# how to update active build in google cloud services?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

The project I'm working on uses Google Cloud Services with Firebase. We have some services that run on Google Cloud Run. I cloned a Golang repo and made a small modification to a struct which is a dependency for couple of the Cloud Function Triggers.

I am attempting to get this new code running on the cloud but seem to be missing something. I did the following command:

```bash
gcloud builds submit --config ./cloudbuild.yaml .
```

which completed successfully. I now have that build showing in Google Cloud Builds, however I am unsure of how to make that the active build.

Where do I set this build to be the active build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to worry about activating it. Once you run the command `gcloud builds submit`, you have already created the build and it's active in your builds. So, you don't have to set this build as the active build or anything like that, as it's already in your platforms. This works like this as you can have many active builds in your platform.

In case you want to check your build details, you can access your [Cloud Build page](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build?_ga=2.166447609.616725834.1599114656-387989268.1584431183), select your project and click Open. Once there, just click on a particular build so you will see the Build details page. To view the artifacts of your build, under Build Summary, click Build Artifacts.

In addition to that, if you have more doubts in general on how to use Cloud Build and how it works, this tutorial [Serverless CI/CD —Cloud Build](https://medium.com/serverlessguru/serverless-ci-cd-cloud-build-e8c09e9a1018) has all the details about it.

Comment: With this new knowledge I figured out that there is a separate file with the Cloud functions and their respective triggers in a  'serverless.yml' that is not included in the building of the 'cloudbuild.yaml'... So that is why I was not seeing the desired results.